# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with react-intl-tel-input component

Tags: reactjs, warnings

I have a functional component called signup in which I am using `react-intl-tel-input` for mobile number field. There is only one async axios request which is happening on submitting the form. But still I am getting this warning

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

I want to remove this warning but so far I tried several solutions provided on Stackoverflow does not work. After debugging I found out the warning is generating from `<IntlTelInput />` field from `react-intl-tel-input`.
Please help me out to remove this warning.

Code example:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import IntlTelInput from "react-intl-tel-input";
import axios from "axios";

function Signup() {

const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  const signupData = { email, password, mobile};

  const response = await axios.post(/url, signupData);
}

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<input name="email" type="text" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
<input name="password" type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
<IntlTelInput
                        containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
                        inputClassName="form-control w-100"
                        autoPlaceholder
                        separateDialCode
                        defaultCountry="za"
                        name="mobile"
                        numberType="MOBILE"
                        fieldId="mobile_number"
                        onPhoneNumberChange={(validate, value, countryData) =>
                         setMobile(value)
                        }
                        formatOnInit={false}
                        autoComplete="new-phone"
                      />
<button type="submit">Signup</button>
);

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleSubmit` function, try adding `e.preventDefault()` at the top. Form components will, by default, attempt to submit the form back to your server when the submit button is clicked, which would cause the page to refresh and your component to unmount. `e.preventDefault()` should prevent it from attempting to submit in the first place.

Example

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import IntlTelInput from "react-intl-tel-input";
import axios from "axios";

function Signup() {

const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const signupData = { email, password, mobile};
  const response = await axios.post(/url, signupData);
}

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<input name="email" type="text" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
<input name="password" type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
<IntlTelInput
                        containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
                        inputClassName="form-control w-100"
                        autoPlaceholder
                        separateDialCode
                        defaultCountry="za"
                        name="mobile"
                        numberType="MOBILE"
                        fieldId="mobile_number"
                        onPhoneNumberChange={(validate, value, countryData) =>
                         setMobile(value)
                        }
                        formatOnInit={false}
                        autoComplete="new-phone"
                      />
<button type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
);

export default Signup;
```

Edit: Also it looks like you didn't add a closing `form` tag, so I just added that in the code above.

Comment: Thank you. But the warning persist even after e.preventDefault(). I realised lator that in axios then block i have set Loading(false) and then redirecting it to another route. That is why the React is trying to update component after its unmount. Thank you for help.